# Tried to determine if a object is in an array if so push object to it if not I do something else

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Let me edit this I made it a tad confusing at first I think.

Ok, this is a school project. I am not asking for anyone to do it I am stuck on one part. I just need guidance on how to get unstuck. I am making a very basic shopping cart using Vue.js. When a user clicks a button to add item to cart the object goes into an array called gamesBought. I need it to be able to determine if a specific object is in the array and if not I need to push the object to the array. In my code I have 3 object made already with a unique name for each. I need to determine if one of them is already in the array and which one. I have 2 attempts in the code one is commented out. I looked them up on stack overflow but I cannot get it to work.

```
var app = new Vue({
    el:"#app",

    data: {
        items:
        [
            {name:"COD: Black Ops 4", quantity: 4, price: 49.99, ordered: 0, total: 0 ,imgSrc:"cod.png"},
            {name:"Fallout 76", quantity: 6, price: 59.99, ordered: 0, total: 0, imgSrc:"fallout.png"},
            {name:"Red Dead Redemption 2", quantity: 5, price: 39.99, ordered: 0, total: 0, imgSrc:"reddead.png"}
        ],
        gameName: "",
        netTotal: 0,
        gamesBought: [],        
        descriptions: ["Black Ops 4 takes the top-selling franchise in Call of Duty® to new heights. The title is tailored to the millions of Call of Duty: Black Ops fans worldwide who continue to engage and play together. Forget what you know, Call of Duty: Black Ops 4 is set to deliver a revolutionary experience.","Do you have nerves of steel? An ironclad will? Average hygiene and an affinity for pre-packaged goods? Then Vault-Tec WANTS you! If you think you have what it takes to be a Vault 76 Test Subject – and enjoy prolonged confinement without sunlight – then you’re in luck! Join the proud ranks of Vault 76 today.","America, 1899. The end of the Wild West era has begun. After a robbery goes badly wrong in the western town of Blackwater, Arthur Morgan and the Van der Linde gang are forced to flee. With federal agents and the best bounty hunters in the nation massing on their heels, the gang must rob, steal and fight their way across the rugged heartland of America."]
    },    

    methods: {
        orderItem(theItem){   

            this.gameName = theItem.name;

            for(game in gamesBought) {
                var g = gamesBought.indexOf(game);
                if(typeof gamesBought !== 'undefined' && gamesBought.length > 0) {
                    if(game.name == gamesBought[g].name){
                            theItem.ordered++;
                            theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                            theItem.quantity--;      
                            this.total += theItem.total;
                        }else                     
                        {
                            theItem.ordered++;
                            theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                            this.gamesBought.push(theItem);
                            theItem.quantity--;      
                            this.total += theItem.total;
                        }
                }
                if (!gamesBought.some(item => item === theItem)) {
                    gamesBought.push(theItem);
                    theItem.ordered++
                    theItem.total = theItem.price*theItem.ordered;
                    theItem.quantity--;
                    total += theItem.total;
                }else{
                    ttheItem.ordered++;
                    theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                    theItem.quantity--;
                    this.total += theItem.total;
                }

                // if(game.name == gamesBought[g].name){
                //     theItem.ordered++;
                //     theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                //     theItem.quantity--;      
                //     this.total += theItem.total;
                // }else                     
                // {
                //     theItem.ordered++;
                //     theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                //     this.gamesBought.push(theItem);
                //     theItem.quantity--;      
                //     this.total += theItem.total;
                // }
            }  

        },
        removeItem(anItem){
            theItem.ordered--;
            var index = this.gamesBought.indexOf(anItem);
            this.gamesBought.splice(index, 1);
            theItem.quantity++;
            this.total -= theItem.total;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if an object is an array using `Array.isArray`:

```
Array.isArray([]) // true
Array.isArray({length: 0}) // false
```

That being said, switching logic based on variable type is generally an indication of bad design; you're writing the code, so you should already know what types your variables are.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the Object type (Object vs. Array) using the `.constructor` property. So given an array named `Arr`, do `Arr.constructor` and it will return 'Array', if it were an object, it would return 'Object`'

You can find examples here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor#Examples

```js
let something = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let somethingelse = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
console.log(something.constructor);
//in an if statement
if (something.constructor == Array) {
  console.log('something is an Array');
}
console.log(somethingelse.constructor);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I was looking at the problem wrong and went about it wrong and I have got it done and working how I needed it to work. Thank you for those who took the time to answer my question.

```
if(this.gamesBought.length > 0){
                if(theItem.sold == true){
                    if(theItem.quantity >= 0){

                                theItem.ordered++;
                                theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                                theItem.quantity--;

                                this.total += theItem.total;

                    }else{
                        this.disabled = 1;
                        theItem.quantity = 0;
                    }                    
                }else{
                    theItem.sold = true;
                    theItem.ordered++;
                    theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                    this.gamesBought.push(theItem);                
                    theItem.quantity--;
                    if(theItem.quantity == 0){
                        this.disabled = 1;
                        theItem.quantity = 0;
                    }
                    this.total += theItem.total;
                }

            }else{                
                theItem.sold = true;
                theItem.ordered++;
                theItem.total = theItem.price * theItem.ordered;
                this.gamesBought.push(theItem);                
                theItem.quantity--;
                if(theItem.quantity == 0){
                    this.disabled = 1;
                    theItem.quantity = 0;
                }
                this.total += theItem.total;
            }
```